# How to create list of links to files in a folder and annotate them using org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I am trying to use org-mode to make a list of files to read, with links to pdfs and write the notes corresponding to it in one file. 
Using [org-fstree](https://github.com/JayDugger/.emacs.d/tree/master/el-get/org-fstree), I can get list of all links as headlines

```
#+BEGIN_FSTREE: ~/path/to/folder 

and pressing C-c C-c.
```

This list can be updated if files are added and removed by C-c C-c again. 
However the problem is that this removes all the notes written.

Is there a way to update this list while keeping all the annotations?

Or any other package or method to get list of all files with their annotations?

(I also tried org-annotate-file.el but that doesnt seem to work either.)

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure just what you mean by a *list of all files with their annotations*.

You can certainly create a *bookmark* to a list of files (e.g. a Dired buffer, which can itself list any set of arbitrary files, from anywhere).  And you can *annotate* a bookmark. (You can also bookmark individual files, of course, which means that you can annotate them individually.)

If you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then the annotation is in *Org mode*, by default.

If you use [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then it is easier to create a Dired buffer that lists arbitrary files.

If for some reason you don't want a Dired buffer, but just a list of file names with links to their files, you can use function `diredp-list-files` (from *Dired+*) to create it.  If you use *Bookmark+* then you can bookmark that buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Would this allow me to open the files by clicking on the link? It's not only a list of files but of links to these files.

Comment: Yes, each of the solutions I mentioned would. There are many ways to get a list of file links - no doubt you will get several other suggestions.

Comment: The above solution works well for txt files but not for opening external files like pdfs. The pdf opened with emacs only show the first page. Also, I had in mind annotating the linked files, sort of wiki where I can write notes and visit the link if required. Thanks for letting me know about annotation for bookmark itself. Any solutions for this setup?

Comment: Bookmarks to PDF files work fine, and so can you open a PDF from Dired. For Bookmark+, see option [`bmkp-default-handlers-for-file-types`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkingFilesYouCannotVisitWithEmacs) (and [Windows file associations](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#WindowsFileAssociations) - and `M-RET` in Dired - if you are on MS Windows).

Comment: If the linked files are bookmarked individually (or if the links are bookmark links), then each file gets its own annotation: the [annotation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkAnnotations) of the associated bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [org-mac-link](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mac-link.html), which can pull links to a specific page in a PDF in [Skim PDF](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using org-mac-link. The positive with org fstree is that all the links can be pulled in one command